# Creating function barcode asp FPDF

Tags: asp-classic, fpdf

awhile ago escontrei this library, "https://sites.google.com/site/aspfpdf/tutorials" - based on FPDF, php, but facing ASP, I'm using it to make mounting a bank, but when trying to mount a function to set the barcode'm facing the following problem.

Below code FPDF!

```
this.Codabar=function Codabar(xpos, ypos, code) {
        var start='A';
        var end='A';
        var basewidth=0.35;
        var height=16;
    barChar = array (
        '0' = array (6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 17.9),
        '1' = array (6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 24.3, 6.5),
        '2' = array (6.5, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 18.6),
        '3' = array (17.9, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5),
        '4' = array (6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 6.5),
        '5' = array (17.9,    10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 6.5),
        '6' = array (6.5, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9),
        '7' = array (6.5, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5),
        '8' = array (6.5, 24.3, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5),
        '9' = array (18.6, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 6.5),
        '$' = array (6.5, 10.0, 18.6, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 6.5),
        '-' = array (6.5, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 18.6, 10.0, 6.5),
        ':' = array (16.7, 9.3, 6.5, 9.3, 16.7, 9.3, 14.7),
        '/' = array (14.7, 9.3, 16.7, 9.3, 6.5, 9.3, 16.7),
        '.' = array (13.6, 10.1, 14.9, 10.1, 17.2, 10.1, 6.5),
        '+' = array (6.5, 10.1, 17.2, 10.1, 14.9, 10.1, 13.6),
        'A' = array (6.5, 8.0, 19.6, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 6.5),
        'T' = array (6.5, 8.0, 19.6, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 6.5),
        'B' = array (6.5, 16.1, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 8.0, 19.6),
        'N' = array (6.5, 16.1, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 8.0, 19.6),
        'C' = array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 19.6),
        '*' = array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 19.6),
        'D' = array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 19.6, 16.1, 6.5),
        'E' = array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 19.6, 16.1, 6.5));
    this.SetFont('Arial','',13);
    this.Text(xpos, ypos + height + 4, code);
    this.SetFillColor(0);
    code = strtoupper(start.code.end);
    for(i=0; i<strlen(code); i++){
        char = code[i];
        if(!isset(barChar[char])){
            this.Error('Invalid character in barcode: '.char);
        }
        seq = barChar[char];
        for(bar=0; bar<7; bar++){
            lineWidth = basewidth*seq[bar]/6.5;
            if(bar % 2 == 0){
                this.Rect(xpos, ypos, lineWidth, height, 'F');
            }
            xpos += lineWidth;
        }
        xpos += basewidth*10.4/6.5;
    }
}
```

The PDF document - is well

```
    pdf.SetXY 60,260
pdf.Codabar 80,40,strCodigoBarras,0,0
```

erro 
Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a138f'

Object expected

/exec/boleto/fpdf.asp, line 2679->This line, no this present in document

Comment: First of all you posted it with wrong tag: from the look of it this like JavaScript or remotely like one of ASP.NET language question not a classic ASP. Second what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Codabar=function Codabar(xpos, ypos, codice) {
        var basewidth=0.35;
        var height=16;
        var barChar=new Array();
        barChar['0'] = new Array (6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 17.9);
        barChar['1'] = new Array (6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 24.3, 6.5);
        barChar['2'] = new Array (6.5, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 18.6);
        barChar['3'] = new Array (17.9, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5);
        barChar['4'] = new Array (6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 6.5);
        barChar['5'] = new Array (17.9,    10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 24.3, 6.5);
        barChar['6'] = new Array (6.5, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9);
        barChar['7'] = new Array (6.5, 24.3, 6.5, 10.4, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5);
        barChar['8'] = new Array (6.5, 24.3, 17.9, 10.4, 6.5, 10.4, 6.5);
        barChar['9'] = new Array (18.6, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 6.5);
        barChar['$'] = new Array (6.5, 10.0, 18.6, 24.4, 6.5, 10.0, 6.5);
        barChar['-'] = new Array (6.5, 10.0, 6.5, 24.4, 18.6, 10.0, 6.5);
        barChar[':'] = new Array (16.7, 9.3, 6.5, 9.3, 16.7, 9.3, 14.7);
        barChar['/'] = new Array (14.7, 9.3, 16.7, 9.3, 6.5, 9.3, 16.7);
        barChar['.'] = new Array (13.6, 10.1, 14.9, 10.1, 17.2, 10.1, 6.5);
        barChar['+'] = new Array (6.5, 10.1, 17.2, 10.1, 14.9, 10.1, 13.6);
        barChar['A'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 19.6, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 6.5);
        barChar['T'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 19.6, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 6.5);
        barChar['B'] = new Array (6.5, 16.1, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 8.0, 19.6);
        barChar['N'] = new Array (6.5, 16.1, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 8.0, 19.6);
        barChar['C'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 19.6);
        barChar['*'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 6.5, 16.1, 19.6);
        barChar['D'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 19.6, 16.1, 6.5);
        barChar['E'] = new Array (6.5, 8.0, 6.5, 19.4, 19.6, 16.1, 6.5);
    this.SetFont('Arial','',13);
    this.Text(xpos, ypos + height + 4, codice);
    this.SetFillColor(0);
    codice = 'A'+codice.toUpperCase()+'A';
    for(i=0; i<codice.length; i++){
        char = codice.charAt(i);
        if (typeof barChar[char] === 'undefined') {
            this.Error('Invalid character in barcode: '+char);
        }
        seq = barChar[char];
        for(bar=0; bar<7; bar++){
            lineWidth = basewidth*seq[bar]/6.5;
            if(bar % 2 == 0){
                this.Rect(xpos, ypos, lineWidth, height, 'F');
            }
            xpos += lineWidth;
        }
        xpos += basewidth*10.4/6.5;
    }
}
```